# How can I alternate my array by twos?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, A and B, that I want to merge and display in this order:

```
A0 B0 A1 B1
B2 A2 B3 A3
A4 B4 A5 B5
B6 A6 B7 A7
```

So far this is what I have:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) {

    if(...) {

        $mergeArray[] = $a[$i];
        $mergeArray[] = $b[$i];

    } else {

        $mergeArray[] = $b[$i];
        $mergeArray[] = $a[$i];
    }
}

return $mergeArray;
```

What do the numbers `0,1,4,5,8,9,12,13...` all have in common?

Comment: i dont see why your creating a new array, for display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is that when you divide by four, you should get the reminder 0 or 1:

```
if($i % 4 == 0 || $i % 4 == 1) { //...
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
if($i % 4 < 2) { //...
```

Comment: Thanks @Anders. While my display issue was solved (above), this is the real answer to my question. Very clever!

Answer (score 4):

i believe this is what you want:

```
<?php

$a=array('a0','a1','a2','a3','a4','a5');
$b=array('b0','b1','b2','b3','b4','b5');

$sum = count($a);

for($i = 0; $i < $sum; $i ++){

    if ($i % 2 == 0){
        echo $a[$i] . ' ' . $b[$i] . ' ' . $a[$i + 1] . ' ' . $b[$i + 1] . "<br>";
    }else{
        echo $b[$i] . ' ' . $a[$i] . ' ' . $b[$i + 1] . ' ' . $a[$i + 1] . "<br>";
    }

    $i ++;
}
```

output:

```
a0 b0 a1 b1
b2 a2 b3 a3
a4 b4 a5 b5
```

Comment: No, that results in: `A0 B0 A1 B1`, `A2 B2 A3 B3`, `A4 B4 A5 B5`, `A6 B6 A7 B7` etc.

I want B to come first when `$i` is `2,3,6,7,10,11...`.

Comment: Thanks @Dagon. You don't need the `$alt` variable though. You can just use `$i`. I think the trick was thinking of the array items in groups of 4, rather than groups of 2.

Comment: @MichaelLynch true that, silly me, removed - don't forget to accept.

Comment: I also realized you need to divide `$sum` by 2, now that you are echoing out two array items per iteration. You're also incrementing `$i` twice. There's no need to increment it after the `if()` statement. It's already in the for loop.

Comment: no you do need to increment twice or you get `a0 b0 a1 b1 |
b1 a1 b2 a2` 2nd row starts at 2 not 1.